# Get status messages of a fanpage

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

i was wondering how to get the latest status messages of my fanpage. But not of fans who postet on my fanpage. So i need a way to filter this.

I already tried sth like this, but it doenst work.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/123456790/feed?from.id=123456790
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this ;-)

```
    $url = "/$pageId/posts?access_token=$accessToken";
    $result = $this->facebook->opengraph->api($url);
```